# javac -cp in ubuntu working but java -cp not working

Tags: java

This is working fine

```
hduser@renjith-Inspiron-3542:~/Documents/Skillset_Modify/java_UpSkill$ javac -cp ~/Documents/Skillset_Modify testConstructor.java
```

### This is not working

```
hduser@renjith-Inspiron-3542:~/Documents/Skillset_Modify/java_UpSkill$ java -cp ~/Documents/Skillset_Modify testConstructor
```

Error:

```
 Could not find or load main class testConstructor
```

Can someone tell me why is it like this?

Comment: you dont have a main class

Comment: Use the fully qualified name of testConstructor class. Does it contain a main method?

Comment: what is the class name of `testConstructor.java` ? class  `yyyyy` {}??

Comment: testConstructor.java is using worker.java in folder ~/Documents/Skillset_Modify thats why i have give -cp.

Comment: And this will work fine when both classes are in same folder. but not working while giving java -cp command

Comment: Check this http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/04/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-helloworld-java.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Try `java -cp ~/Documents/Skillset_Modify;. testConstructor` from `~/Documents/Skillset_Modify/java_UpSkill directory/`

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much now its working with java -cp ~/Documents/Skillset_Modify/: testConstructor

Comment: for javac it wasnt necessary . i dont know whats the difference here.

Comment: javac i used only javac -cp ~/Documents/Skillset_Modify/  testConstructor.java